# PostgreSQL How to Switch/Exchange Partition?

Tags: postgresql, partition, database-partitioning

I have been working on MSSQL and i am using Alter table switch partition command on MSSQL in some of my procedures.
How can i achive the same results on PostgreSQL with good performance?
Is there anyway to switch partitions?

Comment: What exactly does "switch partition" do? Are you maybe looking for detach/attach partition in Postgres

Comment: Thanks for answering, i am looking into that. It seems detach/attach works for me.